# Macbook restarts because of panic error, what is the actual cause?

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

Is this a hardware problem or software problem? How can we rectify?

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8030248a5a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80302c319e, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000074, CR3: 0x0000000000668184, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff8070620000, RCX: 0xffffff8070620224, RDX: 0x0000000000000004
RSP: 0xffffff8043593640, RBP: 0xffffff8043593790, RSI: 0x0000000000000024, RDI: 0x00000000000000d8
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000989680, R10: 0x0000000000000002, R11: 0x0000000000668000
R12: 0x0000000000000024, R13: 0xffffff80435937c0, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff8043593a6c
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff80302c319e, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000074, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80435930a0 : 0xffffff803011c63d 
0xffffff80435930f0 : 0xffffff8030256b25 
0xffffff8043593130 : 0xffffff80302486ae 
0xffffff8043593180 : 0xffffff80300c2a40 
0xffffff80435931a0 : 0xffffff803011bd07 
0xffffff80435932a0 : 0xffffff803011c0f7 
0xffffff80435932f0 : 0xffffff80308c0b5c 
0xffffff8043593360 : 0xffffff8030248a5a 
0xffffff80435934e0 : 0xffffff8030248758 
0xffffff8043593530 : 0xffffff80300c2a40 
0xffffff8043593550 : 0xffffff80302c319e 
0xffffff8043593790 : 0xffffff803032dedb 
0xffffff8043593830 : 0xffffff8030332d1d 
0xffffff8043593b20 : 0xffffff80302b6f92 
0xffffff8043593b40 : 0xffffff8030321fa0 
0xffffff8043593d10 : 0xffffff8030396549 
0xffffff8043593dc0 : 0xffffff8030396aab 
0xffffff8043593ef0 : 0xffffff8030396cfb 
0xffffff8043593f40 : 0xffffff8030783cd7 
0xffffff8043593fa0 : 0xffffff80300c3206 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Code Helper (Ren

Mac OS version:
19H1323

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Jun 22 19:49:55 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.35~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: EA37759C-12E3-3509-AD57-4B4A4FC5E7AD
Kernel slide:     0x000000002fe00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8030000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802ff00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16879532888783
last loaded kext at 14044085568371: >usb.cdc    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fb3a83000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 14181695643771: >usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fb3a83000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.4
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.4
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.7
>!AHDA  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABacklight    180.3
>SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
>!ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AFWOHCI   5.6.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UTCButtons    255
>!UTCKeyboard   255
>!AIR!C 360
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
>AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
|IOFireWireIP   2.3.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IOFireWire!F   4.7.5
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!UMultitouch   264
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    323.4
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 422.120.3
|IOBD!S!F   1.8
|IODVD!S!F  1.8
|IOCD!S!F   1.8
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
|IOAHCISerialATAPI  268
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

This is what i was doing while it happened opened vs  code a folder. it was mounted on xampp while the opened folder files was copying from another location to xampp htdocs. What I know is xampp works in mac like USB mount unmount. What i need to know is whether it is a mac hardware issue or just a software crash

Comment: Isn't `Code Helper (Renderer)` part of MS Visual Studio?  Do you have something connected via USB?  If so, what happens when you unplug it, do you still get a crash?

Comment: @fsb added few more details

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information here to establish preliminary cause. At minimum, we should **enable kernel symbolication** and reproduce the panic to try to understand more about the failure chain. Instructions are below.

The only hint I have from this report is that (1) you are running VirtualBox, which includes four kernel extensions that inject code directly into protected kernel memory, (2) you are running Code Helper, which is presumably a Windows binary that is being executed via VirtualBox, and (3) you may be trying to communicate with a USB serial console device, probably as part of your Windows-based debugging. There is generally an elevated risk of instability when doing this via kernel extensions due to frequently buggy third-party code. So if this happens regularly, **try stopping that workflow (and potentially running the VirtualBox uninstaller)** and see if that resolves your panics.

Here is how to enable kernel panic report symbolication:

1. Run the following Terminal command: `sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`. Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a permission error, you will first need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection). You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. Reboot your machine. The next time this crash happens, your report will have a symbolicated backtrace. Update your question with the new report.

Comment: `Code Helper (Renderer)` is part of Visual Studio Code, which is available as a macOS binary (I'm running it right now). So I doubt the process is run by VirtualBox. One additional thing to check is [running the system diagnose](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to see whether RAM is faulty (rare but happens).