# MacBook Pro 2011, I replaced the logic board but can't get it to work normally

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, install, hardware

I have a Macbook Pro from early 2011 which started to have hardware problems. I bought a used logic board in China and was able to successfully install it as a replacement for the deceased one.

But I have the following problems:

1. The battery or battery charger does not work so the fans run at full speed.
2. I was able to get it to boot but it does not recognize the SSD.
3. I put the original hard disk (unfortunately it had been used for a Windows PC) and tried to install different versions of OS

   - Yosemite USB installation (failure to finish preloading the USB, the computer restarts and the installation begins again)
   - Installation via USB of El Capitan (failure to finish preloading the USB similar to Yosemite) but then I was able to install it with "Clover" and the installable image of El Capitan. The installation was successful but when the Mac tries to start it reboots before finishing the progress bar with the apple at the start. This installation only works failsafe and I cannot start the Diagnostic Mode (<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) nor the Recovery Mode (<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
   - Recovery using Time Machine, since I have a copy of High Sierra, I recovered the complete installation but the behavior is the same. Fails to start unless in Safe Mode.
   - Currently installing a minor version (Mountain Lion) install the first stage, restart and start installing the second stage. It always restarts after 30% and starts again.
4. In the El Capitan version, I uninstalled the drivers for the dedicated video card, hoping that was the problem, but I never got it to boot normally.

I also did all the possible updates and only the installation of "MacBook Pro EFI Firmware Update 2.7" fails because when the Mac restarts to do the update, it restarts again and again and only continues in Safe Mode. When I look for if something needs to be updated, "MacBook Pro EFI Firmware Update 2.7" reappears.

Please if you can tell me what steps to follow or some guide would be saving me.

PS: I am in Argentina and the prices to take this equipment to an official service are exorbitant and unreliable.

I got this booting in safe mode...

```
Anonymous UUID:       FA68BE48-FBB3-5DF7-60AE-31C84802DD15

Mon Jan  1 13:45:58 2001

* Panic Report *
panic(cpu 7 caller 0xffffff800578687f): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f87f37964, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000033, CR3: 0x00000000092ca000, CR4: 0x00000000000626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff801e685580, RCX: 0x0000000000000202, RDX: 0xffffff80e614b77d
RSP: 0xffffff910ff7a890, RBP: 0xffffff910ff7a8c0, RSI: 0xffffff910ff7a960, RDI: 0xffffff801e685580
R8:  0xffffff910ff7a700, R9:  0x0000000000000008, R10: 0x0000000000000010, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff801e685580, R13: 0xffffff7f87fa7658, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000004006
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f87f37964, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000033, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x7, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 7), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff910ff79d10 : 0xffffff800566ae76 
0xffffff910ff79d60 : 0xffffff8005794484 
0xffffff910ff79da0 : 0xffffff8005786654 
0xffffff910ff79e10 : 0xffffff800561ce60 
0xffffff910ff79e30 : 0xffffff800566a8ec 
0xffffff910ff79f60 : 0xffffff800566a6ac 
0xffffff910ff79fc0 : 0xffffff800578687f 
0xffffff910ff7a130 : 0xffffff800561ce60 
0xffffff910ff7a150 : 0xffffff7f8636f553 
0xffffff910ff7a290 : 0xffffff8005cb7ea7 
0xffffff910ff7a2e0 : 0xffffff8005cb79b3 
0xffffff910ff7a320 : 0xffffff8005cb5662 
0xffffff910ff7a360 : 0xffffff800566ad31 
0xffffff910ff7a3b0 : 0xffffff8005794484 
0xffffff910ff7a3f0 : 0xffffff8005786654 
0xffffff910ff7a460 : 0xffffff800561ce60 
0xffffff910ff7a480 : 0xffffff800566a8ec 
0xffffff910ff7a5b0 : 0xffffff800566a6ac 
0xffffff910ff7a610 : 0xffffff800578687f 
0xffffff910ff7a780 : 0xffffff800561ce60 
0xffffff910ff7a7a0 : 0xffffff7f87f37964 
0xffffff910ff7a8c0 : 0xffffff7f87f4f054 
0xffffff910ff7a900 : 0xffffff7f87f4edbc 
0xffffff910ff7a950 : 0xffffff7f87f4ed03 
0xffffff910ff7a9b0 : 0xffffff7f87f4c4b1 
0xffffff910ff7a9f0 : 0xffffff7f87f516d8 
0xffffff910ff7aa20 : 0xffffff7f87f55d54 
0xffffff910ff7aa70 : 0xffffff7f87f76e08 
0xffffff910ff7aaf0 : 0xffffff7f87f781ad 
0xffffff910ff7ab30 : 0xffffff7f87f78e9e 
0xffffff910ff7ab80 : 0xffffff7f87f70360 
0xffffff910ff7abc0 : 0xffffff7f87f74ac1 
0xffffff910ff7ac20 : 0xffffff7f87f2cf23 
0xffffff910ff7acb0 : 0xffffff7f8635ce99 
0xffffff910ff7ad00 : 0xffffff7f8635c34c 
0xffffff910ff7ad20 : 0xffffff7f87fffa71 
0xffffff910ff7ad60 : 0xffffff7f880230b9 
0xffffff910ff7bd20 : 0xffffff7f880244b6 
0xffffff910ff7bd70 : 0xffffff7f88025f91 
0xffffff910ff7be10 : 0xffffff8005c6b2c6 
0xffffff910ff7be60 : 0xffffff7f88009240 
0xffffff910ff7be90 : 0xffffff7f880093de 
0xffffff910ff7beb0 : 0xffffff8005c6e685 
0xffffff910ff7bf00 : 0xffffff8005c7135b 
0xffffff910ff7bf50 : 0xffffff8005c73076 
0xffffff910ff7bfa0 : 0xffffff800561c557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[0249444C-80D4-3184-9060-F70DA3BEB17D]@0xffffff7f86364000->0xffffff7f86380fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[95DA39BB-7C39-3742-A2E5-86C555E21D67]@0xffffff7f8635b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F763C275-306F-358F-B6B0-0FD93486BD5F]@0xffffff7f85e94000
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(6.1)[B0282791-F78C-3A3D-A829-629AD847C7EA]@0xffffff7f87f27000->0xffffff7f87fc2fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[95DA39BB-7C39-3742-A2E5-86C555E21D67]@0xffffff7f8635b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F763C275-306F-358F-B6B0-0FD93486BD5F]@0xffffff7f85e94000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[0249444C-80D4-3184-9060-F70DA3BEB17D]@0xffffff7f86364000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G14042

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Fri Oct 30 13:34:27 PDT 2020; root:xnu-4570.71.82.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 5E83A13A-32F5-3604-8591-50E2F2F70DC6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005500000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 23321620454
last loaded kext at 23023073418: com.apple.kext.AMDLegacySupport    1.6.8 (addr 0xffffff7f88fa1000, size 1187840)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1250.20.1a4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.20.18
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.18
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f22
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.18
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.18
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.7f22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  353
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  404.30.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   186
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.kext.AMDLegacySupport 1.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.21
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.18
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.18
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.18
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.23
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f22
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f22
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f22
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 262
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   267.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.10
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f1
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M, AMD Radeon HD 6490M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353436392D3034362E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353436392D3130362E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.102.30)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f22, 3 services, 27 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SA400S37240G, 240,06 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Comment: I would bet you got a bad system board. I can't be sure but it *sounds* like it. Also you need to trim down your question. AD works best when there is one question at a time, and it is possible that your question will be closed before an answer comes unless you trim it down and focus on **one** question. Once that is answered, ask another.

Comment: Hello, @SteveChambers thank you for your comment, in fact, there is only one question, the numbered points are only to comment a little about my situation and part of the things I did so far to try to solve this problem.

Comment: The statement "The battery or battery charger does not work so the fans run at full speed" has two parts to it. These are not necessarily related statements. Can you elaborate on what you mean by each of these?

Comment: Hi @pion the battery is completely dead and shows a cross over its indicator. The wall power cable let me start the computer. I read that if the battery is not present or dead the fans run at full speed like my case.

Comment: There are likely multiple root issues here. Let's try to attack the boot failure. You mentioned that you can successfully boot High Sierra (from Time Machine) in Safe Mode, correct? If so, can you try to boot it in Verbose Mode (CMD+V during boot), take slow-motion video of the boot process, and upload the screen captures here (via www.PasteBin.com or similar) so that we can examine the boot console text?

Comment: @pion thanks for your time, I edited the question by adding the latest boot report, can you please take a look?
I will do the video capture later.

Comment: I want to thank the editors here because they are doing a great job clarifying what I post. Sincerely thank you very much!

Comment: @Jose Your panic report doesn't contain enough information right now. At minimum, you will need to enable kernel symbolication (while booted into Safe Mode, in your case) and reproduce the panic. See, for example, my answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426591/macbook-restarts-because-of-panic-error-what-is-the-actual-cause/426592#426592

Comment: @pion thanks again for taking the time to help me! At the moment I don't have the computer since I took it to a technician with more tools (and parts of macs) to try my luck ...
And it seems that there is still some luck! Because when he plugged in a running battery, the mac began to behave almost perfectly! At this moment he is doing all kinds of tests and so far everything is fine! Fingers crossed!

Comment: Hi there!

Once again thank you very much for the help!

I have great news!

It was just a matter of putting in the battery and the computer just worked perfectly!

I was able to install High Sierra without any problem.

All programs work fine, only the battery drains extremely fast so I am going to contact the seller tomorrow to ask if there are any charging methods that I am not doing correctly.